# Why doesn't htop display the same processes as top?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, cpu-load, top

I have a home server sometimes running at a high CPU usage rate of about 50 to 70 percents.

In `htop`, my favorite process manager, I can sort the processes by CPU usage, but often there isn't any process consuming more than 0 % CPU. On the other side, `htop` displays the whole CPU usage of the system which is about 50 percents, as said before.

I guess that there is an easy explanation for this, but I don't know it.

Maybe there are some hidden processes? But even running it as root doesn't show more processes.

**EDIT:**

I looked into `top`, which is showing (at least) two more processes:

```
  230 root      20   0     0    0    0 R 37.4  0.0 107:06.59 md127_raid5                                          
20403 root      35  15     0    0    0 D  9.6  0.0   2:45.78 md127_resync
```

So my mdadm raid is currently resyncing, which has been confirmed when I displayed `/proc/mdstat`. (See first comment.)

So this turns the question in: **"Why doesn't htop display the same processes than top?"**

Comment: `top` shows more processes. The process in question belongs to `mdadm`, which is currently performing a resync as I found out. `top` shows the process under the name `md127_raid5` and `md127_resync`. The former is running since booting the system, the latter since resync has been triggered. So this turns the question in: "Why doesn't htop display the same processes than top?"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Why doesn't htop display the same processes than top?

Because `htop` hides kernel threads by default, while top doesn't. You can switch this option off in <kbd>F2</kbd>-settings in `htop`.

1. Before:

   [image]
2. Uncheck the *Hide kernel threads* setting, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave screen instead of `F10`.

   [image]
3. Notice the new number of `kthr` (kthreads) at the cursor, and all the new `k...` processes that have shown up. You can sort these by CPU, etc. as usual. Apart from the name (begins with a *k*, has a `/` towards the end), you can also identify kernel threads by their *very low* PIDs (notice the 1, 2, 3...17 in the screenshot?)

   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is something I wanted to know for years! And the solution is so simple... Thanks for the nice screenshots :)

Comment: The hotkey is H (shift+h).

Comment: @glebm (late, but I think it's worth to add ;) ): The hotkey for displaying _kernel_ threads is `K` (Shift+k). The hotkey `H` (Shift+h) displays (or hides, if already displayed) _userland_ threads.

Comment: Can htop also  hides all the idle processes like `top -i`?